# Woocommerce: How to change the attribute values per product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is it possible (or have you seen a plugin) to change the ordering of the attribute values for particular product? Here is our scenario: we are building a bookstore. Each book (product) has attribute Authors with one or several entries. But the order of appearance of these authors is important to us and it is not global. For example author A might appear before author B on book X but on book Y, the order to be B then A. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your admin panel edit the attribute "Authors" and set the order as Custom.

Now you can use a csv to edit all your products and attributes for each one. The order you will set there, that's the order that will be displayed in each product.

About Woocommerce default csv import / export function you can read more here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-importer-exporter/

Comment: thank you for your time! just a quick question - do you know of a plugin that can rearrange after they are imported? I would like to give the admins option to reorder the authors